# Javascript converting 24 hour clock to 12 hour clock

Tags: javascript, css

i am trying to make a css3 clock and the javascript i have only gives me the 24 hour time but i need the 12 hour time here is the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DmlJi

Comment: `if (hour > 12) hour - 12 && it's in the evening`

Comment: where do i put this? i dont code javascript I was given the code

Comment: You don't put it anywhere, it's just pseudo code trying to tell you that if the hour is more than twelve you'd subtract twelve. Say it's 23, subtracting 12 you get 11, or if it's 13, then subtracting 12 would give you 1. It's a matter of kindergarten math to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your pen, something like this.

```
drawHour : function(time){
    var offset = 0;
    if (time[0] > 12){
      offset = 12;
    }
    this.drawDigits(this.hour, time[0]-offset);  
}
```